# Multiply columns of a matrix by different numbers in Python

Tags: python

I have a matrix hsa in a script. Now I want to multiply its 1st column by sqrt(2), 2nd column by sqrt(2), and 3rd column by 1 using numpy to create a resultant matrix HSA(expected)? I used the given code and it did not work.

```js
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
hs = np.loadtxt('HS', skiprows=8)

from itertools import islice
with open('HS') as lines:
array = np.genfromtxt(islice(lines, 2, 5))

lv=np.diag(array)

hsa=hs*lv
print (hsa)

HSA= [sqrt(2)*hsa(:,1), sqrt(2)*hsa(:,2), 1*hsa(:,1)]
print (HSA)


hsa= 
             [[1     0     5]
             [1      0     7]
             [1      0     9]
             [1      0     5]
             [1      0     6]
             [1      0     4]
             [1      0     5]
             [0      1     6]
             [0      1     1]
             [0      1     7]
             [0      1     3]
             [0      1     3]
             [0      1     5]]
        
        
  
        
      (Expected) HSA= 
             [[1.414 0     5]
             [1.414  0     7]
             [1.414  0     9]
             [1.414  0     5]
             [1.414  0     6]
             [1.414  0     4]
             [1.414  0     5]
             [0      1.414 6]
             [0      1.414 1]
             [0      1.414 7]
             [0      1.414 3]
             [0      1.414 3]
             [0      1.414 5]]
```

Comment: I don't see hs*lv in your code

Comment: Please write your expected result also

Comment: Your matrix is poorly formatted as you have no comma to separated lines. Please make an effort about presenting a working piece of code so we can help.

Comment: Can you please check now? @SreeramTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy can directly broadcast over the first dimensions:

```
HSA = hsa * np.array([np.sqrt(2.), np.sqrt(2.), 1])
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. It shows the error "name 'sqrt' is not defined".

Comment: @Kish: **you** wrote `sqrt(2)` in your question. Just replace it with `np.sqrt`

Comment: @Kish: and where can your read `HSA= [np.sqrt(2)*hsa(:,1), np.sqrt(2)*hsa(:,2), 1*hsa(:,1)]` in my answer?

Comment: Sorry for that misunderstanding. I used your code 
HSA = hsa * np.array([np.sqrt(2.), np.sqrt(2.), 1]) and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much. @Serge

Comment: I misunderstood. This is my first time here writing on this platform. I hope you understand. Sorry for that. It really helps me. @Serge